# How do I edit a record in a modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I have a rails app that displays records in a table. I wanna be able to click edit button and it should display a modal with form to edit the record.

I dont know how to load the object in realtime when edit button is clicked. Loading all objects would be overkill right?

is there any technique to do this?

Comment: You can respond in js format with edit.js.erb template.

Comment: in your large display list, give each item a `data-itemid=yourItemId` then use ajax to get the record

Comment: you need to provide some code to help you mate..

Answer (score 0):

You can pull a single record and pop a modal dialog for edit. For example in your controller define a edit method and pull a single record @record = Record.find(params[:record_id]).

Answer (score -1):

Rails gives the edit feature if you follow its conventions.

Either you create your own or you generate using scaffolding and then customize.

The latter is easy though---

If you have your rails scaffolding like `rails generate scaffold_controller Club name:string exclusive:boolean`

It will generate:

```
create app/controllers/clubs_controller.rb
invoke erb
create app/views/clubs
create app/views/clubs/index.html.erb
create app/views/clubs/edit.html.erb
create app/views/clubs/show.html.erb
create app/views/clubs/new.html.erb
create app/views/clubs/_form.html.erb
create app/views/layouts/clubs.html.erb
invoke test_unit
create test/functional/clubs_controller_test.rb
```

You see that **edit method** will now be having in controller and its corresponding view in **edit.html.erb**